# problem with event parameters / arguments. (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, parameter-passing, roblox

Basically I have a code that gets fired to a localscript in all players. The speaker / player argument is used to make sure the event is recieved by the correct reciever, and the "allow" argument is a boolean value used for later code. (Don't think about that part).

This is the :FireClient Script

```lua
1   game.ReplicatedStorage.AllowDisallow:FireClient(speaker, true)
```

This is the reciever / localscript

```lua
1   game.ReplicatedStorage.AllowDisallow.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player, allow)
2       if not player.Name == game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name then return end
```

Error:

```
attempt to index boolean with 'Name'
```

My thought is that it erases the player parameter and switches it with the 'allow' bool value. I have tried searching this issue up on google, but I did not find a clear answer.

OTHER INFORMATION:

- There's an event in ReplicatedStorage, which is the one im using.
- It's called "AllowDisallow". Don't think too much about the name.
- The 'allow' argument should be a bool value, and the "player" should be the player.

Sincerely, Mathe

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `player` variable in the LocalScript is a boolean, not a Player object.

When you call a [RemoteEvent's](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent) [FireClient](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireClient) function, the first argument indicates which player it is going to, and all the rest are provided as the arguments in the [OnClientEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnClientEvent) callback. For example,

```
-- if the server calls...
RemoteEvent:FireClient(player, a, b, c)

-- the client will receive...
RemoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(a, b, c) end)
```

You just need to update your receiver LocalScript so that the arguments reflect what the server is providing. Then you can remove the LocalPlayer safety check, because the OnClientEvent *only* fires for the LocalPlayer.

```
local allowDisallow = game.ReplicatedStorage.AllowDisallow
allowDisallow.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(allow)
    -- do some stuff
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to print out the arguments in the server event and check whats wrong